# Make-shift string boolean?

Tags: java

I am attempting to create a sort of settings system for a project I am creating, however I have hit somewhat of a problem. I'm trying to use a string (considering these settings must later be saved to a text file) as a make-shift boolean. So, I need to be able to switch this string between true and false. I assumed the following method would work, but for some reason it always sets to true regardless. This is, as far as I know, the only place in the code where the variable is set.

I have no idea why the following code shouldn't work, and I've done thorough searching to no avail.

```
if("true".equals(settings[0])) 
   settings[0] = "false";             //This is *always* skipped
else if("false".equals(settings[0])) 
   settings[0] = "true";`
```

Therefore, I've come here.

Comment: When some data is a boolean value, you should use a boolean. When saved as a string, transform this boolean to a string. When loaded, transform the string to a boolean. Your code will be more readable, more efficient, and more robust if you follow this rule.

Comment: Did you check what `settings[0]` actually contains? This is the time where the compiler shines :)

Comment: This fragment works correctly, as long as `settings[0]` is `"true"` or `"false"`. What's the initial value of `settings`?

Comment: @MarounMaroun Yes, by default it's equal to "false".

Comment: @NukeDuck The boolean true? or the String?

Comment: @MarounMaroun The String value.

Comment: @NukeDuck Can you please post more of your code?

Comment: The array settings[] itself is strictly a String array.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I'm unsure which other part of the code this is applicable to.

Comment: I agree with @JBNizet. Use `Boolean#toString` to convert to a string and `Boolean#valueOf` to get a boolean from a string.

Comment: @NukeDuck The part where you set settings[0]

Comment: `public static String[] settings = new String[]
 {
  "false",
  "true",
  "true",
  "false"
 };`

Comment: Is `settings[0]` changed anywhere else? Does the code in the question ever access anything other than index 0 of `settings`?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard No, conducting a Project-wide Search shows that there are no other references to settings[0] other than here.

Comment: We may need to see more of your code. Is that snippet in a loop? As it stands, it looks like `settings[0]` always starts as `"false"`, so after the `if` block it will always be `"true"`.

Comment: I should have listened to the earlier comments slightly closer, because it _is_, of course, much easier and more robust to convert the string from boolean and to boolean to make this process much easier. I thank everyone for their help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert string to bool and inverse result. Sample

```
String[] settings = {"tRue"};
boolean settingBool = !Boolean.parseBoolean(settings[0]);
System.out.println(settingBool);
```

Output:

```
false
```

Comment: Thank you, doing this rather than my original, rather messy method seems to have worked. I'm not sure why, but it's a solution nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to use booleans in the first place and only convert them to strings and back if you need to.

As JB Nizet wrote in his comment, it would make the code far more readable and robust.
In your case, that would mean keeping boolean values instead of strings:

```
public static Boolean[] settings = new Boolean[] { Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.TRUE,
                                                  Boolean.TRUE, BOOLEAN.FALSE };
```

To toggle the boolean, use

```
settings[0] = !settings[0];
```

To convert to string for saving the setting, use `Boolean#toString`, for reading from settings `Boolean#valueOf(String)`.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing the comments:

> Did you check what settings[0] actually contains?
>
> Yes, by default it's equal to "false".
>
> Is settings[0] changed anywhere else?
>
> No

If settings[0] is false, then you **should** expect the first branch of your if statement to always be skipped.